# typescript passing array of numbers/string to function

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am bit struck on this.

**Single Request:**

1. Using Model binding two input boxes has been passed to my typescript function where it takes two argument and display output which works really fine. Below is my sample function.

   ```
   convert(X, Y) {
    this.output = X * Y;

   console.log("Output:", this.output);

   }
   ```
2. **Bulk Request**

Another scenario is:

I have a input textarea where users can copy and paste bulk of data from Excel / txt file. Where I would like to pass every line in to my above typescript function. How do I let `\t and \n` to my typescript function

[image]

I have also created stackblitz for this. Can any one please help. Thanks.

Stackblitz Editor URL: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-passing-srting-array-to-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function bulkConvert(text: string) {
  const pairs = text
    .split(/\n/) // split by line
    .map(pair => pair
      .split(/[\s]+/) // split by whitespace
      .map(numString => parseFloat(numString)) // parse string to number
    ); 
  const results = pairs.map(([x, y]) => x * y);
  // then do whatever you want with results, I think you want this.outputBulk = results;
}
```

Comment: My hearty thanks for this. I have a scenario like this  `const results = pairs.map(([x, y]) => [this.convert(x, y)]);` where I am passing x and Y to another function. I wanted to save the output of what is being converted but when I try to save I am keep getting null in my variable.

Comment: It wont work with `this.convert(x, y)` if this method is implemented the way it is in your original post. If you want to reuse it, you should split `convert(x, y)` into two methods - one that does the calculation and returns the result (so essentially just `return x*y;`) and the other one that saves the result to `this.output`. Then you can use the method that does calculations in both bulk and single arguments scenarios.